# Redirect Codeigniter user when using back button

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

If the user hits their browser's Back button directly after logging into my Codeigniter web app they're taken back to the login form. Instead I'd like the user to be directed to the homepage.

Also, when the user logs out, I'd like to prevent access to the Account page, but I have no idea how to do this either.

Any suggestions?

I have attached my login model below.

Controller:

```
class Account extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('masterentry_model');
    $this->load->model('account_model');
    // Your own constructor code
}
public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != TRUE){//checking loged in
    $this->load->view('signin'); 
    }else{
        $data['location'] = $this->masterentry_model->getLocation();
        $data['activeUser'] = $this->masterentry_model->userActive();
        $data['flag'] = "home";
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        //redirect('account');
    }
}

//login process
public function loginsum(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|callback_check_exists');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE) 
        {
            //$path =  get_redirect_path();

            redirect('account');
        }
    }
    else{
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != TRUE) 
        { 
        $this->load->view('signin');
        }
        else
        {
        redirect('account');    
        }
    }
}

//check email and password with database correct or not 
public function check_exists($password){
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $result = $this->account_model->logincheck($email, $password);
    if($result == 0)
    {   
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_exists', 'Email (or) Password incorrect');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;    
    }

}

//logout process 
public function logout(){
    $session_array = array(
            'email' => "",
            'user_id' => "",
            'logged_in' => FALSE
        );

        $this->session->unset_userdata($session_array);

        $this->index();
}

}
```

Model:

```
class Account_model extends CI_Model{

 function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
 }

 public function logincheck($email, $password){
    //echo "SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password)'";
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '".md5($password)."'");

    //checking row existes
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        $row = $query->row();
        $session_array = array(
            'email' => $row->email,//storing email in session 
            'user_id' => $row->id,//storing userid in session 
            'logged_in' => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_array);

        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Minor grammar changes to hopefully clarify intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include these headers in the `constructor function` of the `controller` to prevent the caching of previous page

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: Hi, after my logout application my url going like this(http://localhost/barteradmin/account/logout) after that i loged in means and click back button means my url going like this(http://localhost/barteradmin/account/logout) after that my application getting loged out. I want to do like facebook application.

Comment: yes, its not working. My browser going back after login. After logout its working.